# Why youtube api v3.0 thumb file image has black bars on top and bottom

Tags: json, youtube

I am attempting to resolve why I get two black bars in YouTube V3.0 JSON response thumb files images.

Following is what I get in JSON response (thumbnail section). If I put this link `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YnIRfvFLiWQ/default.jpg` to browser address bar I see 2 black bars on top and bottom of the picture. But if I search the video (ID `YnIRfvFLiWQ`) in Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnIRfvFLiWQ), and if I right click the tmumb image I see this address https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/YnIRfvFLiWQ/mqdefault.webp as the thumb file url which shows without black bars on top and bottom of the picture. Any idea why this clean picture url does not return in JSON file below?

```
"thumbnails": {
 "default": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YnIRfvFLiWQ/default.jpg",
  "width": 120,
  "height": 90
 },
 "medium": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YnIRfvFLiWQ/mqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 320,
  "height": 180
 },
 "high": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YnIRfvFLiWQ/hqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 480,
  "height": 360
 },
 "standard": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YnIRfvFLiWQ/sddefault.jpg",
  "width": 640,
  "height": 480
 },
 "maxres": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YnIRfvFLiWQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "width": 1280,
  "height": 720
 }
```